# Integrating for speed

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation

Trying to determine the speed of a falling body with respect to traveled distance and initial speed. I've been provided with the following equation for acceleration as a function of distance and the grav. parameter(constant) of the attracting body :

$a=GM/r^2$

Where:

$a$ - acceleration.
$GM$ - gravitational parameter(constant).
$r$ - distance to the attracting body.

I have entered inputs for $GM$ and $r$ and integrated this equation with respect to $r$. This obviously yielded total acceleration per traveled distance, in other words $m^2/s^2$ at the given altitude.

How do I proceed to determine speed at this altitude?

Comment: *integrated this equation* can you provide the steps and the result?

Comment: Cross-posted from http://math.stackexchange.com/q/731741/

Answer (score 1):

I will give you a starting point:

- You could solve this problem by equating the change in potential energy with the change in kinetic energy, $\Delta P.E. = \Delta K.E.$
- You could solve the problem with calculus starting from
  $$
  F=ma=mdv/dt=mvdv/dr=F_{gravity}(r)\Rightarrow\\
  \int mv dv = \int F_{gravity}(r) dr
  $$

Even better: solve it both ways and check your answers are identical.

Comment: in fact you should try to convince yourself that the methods are identical from the definitions of potential and kinetic energy. these two methods are really the same method.